# Filtering Search-ADAccount

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-cmdlet

I am wondering if there is a way to filter this:

> Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -DateTime ((get-date).adddays(-90))
>   -Usersonly

By adding pipeline:

> | where-object {($_.samAccountName -notlike "*_ua1") -and ($ _.memberOf -like "*UserAdminL1 *")}

It seems like it freezes and do nothing.

Maybe there is a correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search-ADAccount does not return group memberships. If you want to filter on that you could first pipe into `Get-AdUser` to get the `memberOf` property. You also are missing the `Where-Object` portion of your filter and the `$ _.memberOf` should be `$_.memberOf`. Compile errors would have been trying to correct that for you so you might just have a copy paste issue with your question.

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -DateTime ((get-date).adddays(-90)) -Usersonly | 
    Get-Aduser -Properties memberof | 
    Where-Object {($_.samAccountName -notlike "*_ua1") -and ($_.memberOf -like "*UserAdminL1 *")}
```

Comment: Hmm, I will try this. Ye forgot to add  get-aduser part. About blank spaces its just mistype :) . Will try to correct .

Comment: i think it worked :) not sure about final outup but now it comes with correct users :)

Comment: Still going slowly and really small amount of users in the output .. something is wrong, any suggestions? oh also in where is the samaccout part its should be -notlike. :)

Comment: @Dambre the logic is correct and does return users for me when i changed the search to something in my own org. You need to examine the output at every pipe and manually check the output to see if its what you are looking for. I notice that you changed your `-like` which is good you are debugging. Is `"*UserAdminL1 *"` is supposed to have a space at the end?

Comment: no I just cant right without it cuz then the UseAdminL1 becomes Italic because of '*'  also with '_' :))

Comment: Hmm, Cant get the right output... My logic is to find all disabled users then filter the output who have no _ua1 in the end and who are in UserAdminL1 group . Could you correct me if i am wrong? Because it starts to frustrate me :/

Comment: The strange thing when it stucks . I try to stop it by ctrl+c it give me few more names and then this error :
`Search-ADAccount : The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context.`

Comment: How big of a result do you expect? While this does work it sounds like you are running out of resources and we might need to take a different approach. Try using `-ResultPageSize 500` with `Search-ADAccount` and see what happens. @Dambre

Comment: Left my VM working, will check it tommorow . Will try your suggestion with pagesize if it wont work. :) Btw expected result is hundreds ( checked that mannually in active directory application )..

Comment: Ok didnt make it to leave my work because of the same error. :D Ok now left it with your suggestion :)

Comment: With that amount of processing might need to break this out of the pipe and let each command function on its own.

Comment: Hi , I am at work and i noticed that no errors came up but the output is really small ... Hm , could you advice me how to put output to another command ? Or should i put it into a file and then read from it?

Comment: @dambre try raising the result size now.

Comment: K . Now i am waiting.

Comment: If your org really has that many users I suggest that you look into  [adsisearcher](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/7943bab9-6ece-40b8-b50b-ec1e16eb1bdb/use-powershell-to-find-and-remove-inactive-active-directory-users-from-multiple-domain-controllers?forum=ITCG) which might be more efficient for this.

Comment: ok , closing this question , found something useful in your link , thanks :)